# Sql Server Query By Weekday With Day not Starting at Midnight

Tags: c++, sql-server

I've written a query that checks the individual row counts for 7 days in 1 week.
Is there a way to rewrite this query in order to not have to type in each individual day? I'm going to be using this with a c++ Application that will execute once a week every sunday at 6PM in the afternoon then list all the days into a textfile.

```
select
sum(case when BankDTS BETWEEN '2015-01-11 18:00' AND '2015-01-12 18:00' then 1 else 0 end) as Monday,
sum(case when BankDTS BETWEEN '2015-01-12 18:00' AND '2015-01-13 18:00' then 1 else 0 end) as Tuesday,
sum(case when BankDTS BETWEEN '2015-01-13 18:00' AND '2015-01-14 18:00' then 1 else 0 end) as Wednesday,
sum(case when BankDTS BETWEEN '2015-01-14 18:00' AND '2015-01-15 18:00' then 1 else 0 end) as Thursday,
sum(case when BankDTS BETWEEN '2015-01-15 18:00' AND '2015-06-16 18:00' then 1 else 0 end) as Friday,
sum(case when BankDTS BETWEEN '2015-01-16 18:00' AND '2015-01-17 18:00' then 1 else 0 end) as Saturday,
sum(case when BankDTS BETWEEN '2015-01-17 18:00' AND '2015-01-18 18:00' then 1 else 0 end) as Sunday
FROM BankHistory
Where BankDTS BETWEEN '2015-01-11 18:00' AND '2015-01-18 18:00' AND Type = 'Debit'
```

Edit: Good Answers, but I'm changing up my question to achieve results from within the group by. The context of the question remains the same.

```
Select count(*) as B
from BankHistory
where BankDTS BETWEEN '2015-01-19 18:00' AND '2015-01-18 18:00'
group by DATEDIFF(dd, 1, BankDTS)
```

I want to change my DateDiff to show for example each day 2015-01-19 18:00 to 2015-01-20 18:00 as 1 day.

Comment: If you had a table built out that contained the dates your looking for you could join against that.

Comment: such as a temp table?

Comment: Sure, temp or real.  A real table would require some maintenance to ensure you always had the dates you query needs available.

Comment: I'm changing my query to do the date within the Group By to achieve my results based on Rows instead of Columns.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the datepart function to find the day of the week.  You can shift the time using the date add function.

```
select
sum(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW,DATEADD(HOUR, 6, BankDTS ))=2 then 1 else 0 end) as Monday,
sum(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW,DATEADD(HOUR, 6, BankDTS ))=3 then 1 else 0 end) as Tuesday,
sum(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW,DATEADD(HOUR, 6, BankDTS ))=4 then 1 else 0 end) as Wednesday,
sum(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW,DATEADD(HOUR, 6, BankDTS ))=5 then 1 else 0 end) as Thursday,
sum(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW,DATEADD(HOUR, 6, BankDTS ))=6 then 1 else 0 end) as Friday,
sum(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW,DATEADD(HOUR, 6, BankDTS ))=7 then 1 else 0 end) as Saturday,
sum(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW,DATEADD(HOUR, 6, BankDTS ))=1 then 1 else 0 end) as Sunday
FROM BankHistory
Where BankDTS BETWEEN '2015-01-11 18:00' AND '2015-01-18 18:00'
```

To change it so that it reports each day as a row it would look like:

```
Select DATEADD(HOUR, 6, BankDTS ) Date,
    DATEPART(DW,DATEADD(HOUR, 6, BankDTS )) Weekday,
    count(*) as B
from BankHistory
Where BankDTS BETWEEN '2015-01-11 18:00' AND '2015-01-18 18:00'
group by DATEADD(HOUR, 6, BankDTS )
order by DATEADD(HOUR, 6, BankDTS )
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a little trickier since you are using the time component but you can use DATEDIFF and DATEPART to determine the offset from your ending date (or starting date).

So your case would use between on a range of seconds (or minutes) the DATEDIFF provides instead of the dates themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
SELECT DATEADD (hh , 18 , DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 1, GETDATE())) ) AS YesterdayAt6PM, DATEADD (hh , 18 , DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) ) AS TodayAt6PM
```

You can tweak the previous query the way you want. Also, prevent duplicate calculations when you can. For instance you can put `GETDATE()` in a separate variable.